# firebase - Create user with email and password returns undefined uid

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on a function in firebase that creates users without logging them in, following a tutorial here on this website. (I decided not to follow the firebase-admin way of adding users due to lack of time). My current problem is when i execute the `CreateUserWithEmailAndPassword` method, it's promise does not work, and does not give a uid at all. The users are also not registering at all. Here is my code used for this:

```
var otherApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDXS11uOZGDmHYuN3J8BJxOG_9vanNakqA",
    authDomain: "pasigueno-assist-1532249634197.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pasigueno-assist-1532249634197.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pasigueno-assist-1532249634197",
    storageBucket: "pasigueno-assist-1532249634197.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "394982410129"
  }, "other");

otherApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(function (user) {
    var uid = user.uid;
    var fullnames = fullname.value;
    var barangays = barangay.value;
    var status = "Active";
    var addresss = address.value;
    var userTypes = userType.value;
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    var storesRef = rootRef.child('users');
    var newStoreRef = storesRef.push();
    newStoreRef.set({
        Address: addresss,
        Name: fullnames,
        Barangay: barangays,
        Username: username,
        UserType: userTypes,
        UserID: uid,
        Status: status
    });
    otherApp.auth().signOut();
    console.log("ok");
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    otherApp.auth().signOut();
});
```

`var otherApp` works as my secondary ref to avoid being kicked out of firebase when signing in regularly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, what kind of object do you get from that [createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) call?  It tells you, you get a [UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential) - which does not have a uid property.  (However it has a [user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) property that has your uid field).

Short answer:

```
otherApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(function (userCreds) {
    var uid = userCreds.user.uid;
    // etc
```

Comment: @IvanAldwinCristobal You should always look a the Reference part of the Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/?authuser=0